# INSERT ALL INTO throws ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to copy a view into a table. Below procedure throws ORA-01722: invalid number

```
BEGIN
   INSERT ALL
     INTO DB_LOCATIONS
      SELECT * FROM DB_LOCVIEW ; 
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      BEGIN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line  ('SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE||'  -SQLERRM: '||SQLERRM);
      END;
END;
```

On the other hand, If I try it with for loop, everything is fine:

```
DECLARE
    currow integer := 1;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('starting.....');
    for xxinserteddata in (select * from DB_LOCVIEW )
    LOOP  
        BEGIN           
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('currow: ' || currow);
            INSERT INTO DB_LOCATIONS ( 
                DB_DATE,
                LOCATIONID,
                MX_ET,
                MX_MT,
                BAND,
                SITE) 
            VALUES (  
                xxinserteddata.DB_DATE,
                xxinserteddata.LOCATIONID,
                xxinserteddata.MX_ET,
                xxinserteddata.MX_MT,
                xxinserteddata.BAND,
                xxinserteddata.SITE );
            currow := currow + 1;
        END;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('end.');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      BEGIN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line  ('-currow: ' || currow || '  -SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE||'  -SQLERRM: '||SQLERRM);
      END;
END;
```

Both view and table has only 5 same columns. Any idea why insert all throws exception?

EDIT:
Adding create procedures:

View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW DB_LOCVIEW ("LOCATIONID", "SITE", "MX_ET", "MX_MT", "DB_DATE", "BAND") AS 
      SELECT 
        l.LOCATIONID,
        l.SITE,
        l.MX_ET,
        l.MX_MT,
        l.CHANGE_DATE AS db_date,
        d.BAND
    FROM ALL_LOCATIONS l
    INNER JOIN LOC_DETATILS d ON (l.location = d.location)
    WHERE l.status = 'ACTIVE' ;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE DB_LOCATIONS 
   (    "LOCATIONID" NUMBER, 
    "DB_DATE" DATE, 
    "MX_ET" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "MX_MT" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "SITE" VARCHAR2(8), 
    "BAND" NUMBER
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DB_DATA" ;
```

Comment: why not use explicit columns listing in the insert (where it fails)?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; and the `INSERT` statements for some sample data. If you have an invalid number errors then that implies that you are trying to put a non-numeric column into a numeric column but we cannot verify that as you have not given any definitions for the tables.

Comment: You're comparing apples and pears. In the loop statements you specify the column names, in the insert all you don't.

Comment: @EduardUta, is there any performance diffrence between insert all and explicit columns listing? View has more then 360k rows.

Comment: Using a cursor is a lot slower than a single `INSERT` SQL statement. There is no effective difference in speed between `INSERT` with implicit column names compared to `INSERT` with explicit column names; however explicitly naming the columns is much less likely to cause bugs in your code.

Comment: @Kuvalya as MT0 also notes (very thorough, nicely done), there is no performance impact on using explicit columns listing vs. implicit. I would advise to always use explicit columns listing as you will avoid future headaches (imagine adding a new column to the table/view that is source of data.. ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not specify the order of the columns in the `INSERT ALL` statement and if the columns of the tables are in different orders then you will find that using `SELECT *` and not specifying the columns will attempt to put the column from one table into the wrong column in the other table.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DB_LOCVIEW (DB_DATE, MX_ET, MX_MT, LOCATIONID, BAND, SITE) AS
SELECT SYSDATE, 'ABC', 'DEF', 1, 23, 'GHI' FROM DUAL;

-- Create the table with the columns in a different order
CREATE TABLE DB_LOCATIONS (DB_DATE, LOCATIONID, MX_ET, MX_MT, BAND, SITE) AS
SELECT DB_DATE, LOCATIONID, MX_ET, MX_MT, BAND, SITE FROM DB_LOCVIEW WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Then running your `INSERT ALL` query fails with the error:

> ```
> SQLCODE: -1722  -SQLERRM: ORA-01722: invalid number
> ```

This is because the statement is effectively expanded to:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT ALL
    INTO DB_LOCATIONS (DB_DATE, LOCATIONID, MX_ET, MX_MT, BAND, SITE)
    SELECT DB_DATE, MX_ET, MX_MT, LOCATIONID, BAND, SITE FROM DB_LOCVIEW; 
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line  ('SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE||'  -SQLERRM: '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

And you can see that the columns do not match. So, even though the columns have identical types, the order of the columns matters.

---

Instead, you can specify the columns and their order:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT ALL
    INTO DB_LOCATIONS (DB_DATE, MX_ET, MX_MT, LOCATIONID, BAND, SITE)
    SELECT DB_DATE, MX_ET, MX_MT, LOCATIONID, BAND, SITE FROM DB_LOCVIEW; 
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line  ('SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE||'  -SQLERRM: '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Or use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and specify the columns:

```sql
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO DB_LOCATIONS (DB_DATE, LOCATIONID, MX_ET, MX_MT, BAND, SITE)
   SELECT DB_DATE, LOCATIONID, MX_ET, MX_MT, BAND, SITE FROM DB_LOCVIEW;
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line  ('SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE||'  -SQLERRM: '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

*Note: You do not need to catch the exception; if there is an error then it will stop the PL/SQL block, implicitly rollback the transaction and print the error trace. Additionally, catching `OTHERS` is considered bad practice. If you do want to catch the exception then you should catch specific expected exceptions then you know when there is an uncaught exception that something unexpected has occurred and you can debug it; if you catch all exceptions then you lose the ability to identify unexpected behaviours.*

Or, without PL/SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO DB_LOCATIONS (DB_DATE, LOCATIONID, MX_ET, MX_MT, BAND, SITE)
SELECT DB_DATE, LOCATIONID, MX_ET, MX_MT, BAND, SITE FROM DB_LOCVIEW;

COMMIT;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8fa523b085429e6e5e903a33997d102a)*

Comment: I checked and the orders of columns are different. Thx. View has more then 360k rows and we must do this every night. Do you have any suggestion for the procedure performance? Is there any diffrence between insert all and explicit column inserting?

Comment: @Kuvalya 360k rows is quite small. Using a cursor loop is a lot slower than a single `INSERT` SQL statement as the cursor loop will generate undo/redo logs for every `INSERT` in each iteration of the loop whereas a single statement will generate a single undo/redo log entry. If you can avoid cursor loops then you should. There is no effective difference in speed between `INSERT` with implicit column names compared to `INSERT` with explicit column names; however, as shown in the answer, explicitly naming the columns is much less likely to cause bugs in your code.